# One controller and inserting data into more than one table (Mass Assignment)

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-4, model, mass-assignment

I have a website that users can send their product *(like car, mobile, computers)* and sell it online on my website, maybe something like Ebay and Amazon.

I have **ads** table that store all public information about one thing using **`Mass Assignment`**, and other categories like Mobile, Car and Computers **have their own table** and will store professional and additional information of that category on it *(for example Cars have some additional information like color, fuel type, guaranty, accidents,insurance)*.

Now as you know *(for mobile)* I have two tables (**ads** and **ads_mobile**), and for all forms I have a controller that is **`adsController`** and **`ads`** model, form will create dynamically and each form has its own inputs (For Example:Mobile and car has different inputs and fields), and I just send all dynamic forms to `adsController@check` and then I check what kind of form it is (is that Mobile? is that Car? or ...?) and then I will send this data to model:

```
//adsController(This is just Example);
 class Ad extends Eloquent {

  protected $fillable_ads = array('field_one', 'field_two', 'field_three');

}

 Class Mobile_ad extends Eloquent {
   //And I want to use fillable_mobile_ads too
   protected $fillable_mobile_ads = array('field_one', 'field_two', 'field_three');
 }
```

**How to send data from one controller to two models?**

Is this possible?

How should be model and controller (suggestion)?

any suggestion for the structure of my website?